# AngularJS perform redirect with request header modified

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm using $http service GET method to send a request for a certain URL that's external. But I want to send some data with this request header. That data will decide the response page.

So far the request is working and I get the HTML page as the response. It is technically a redirect but that HTML will only be given with the request header having the required data, So $location.path('externalUrl') won't do.

Following is the Service code

```
App.service('someService', function($http) {
delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
this.getModule = function(moduleName) {

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/externalURL',
        headers: {'token': 'testToken'}
    });
}
```

});

With this GET request I get the exact response HTML I want. I want the browser to show that HTML.

Is there a way to show the given HTML.

Or is there another way to do this redirection altogether with a modified header?